# SQLite / MySQL use LIKE or REGEXP to match special content words in String

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mysql-workbench

I have a SQLite database table with this structure.

```
    data_table
    |id| string_id | ...
    |1 | 1         | ...
    |2 | 1/111-2   | ...
    |3 | 2/111-2   | ...
    |4 | 2/55-1    | ...
```

"/" and "-" separators are used for the data of "string_id" column.

When the user give input "1", the result should contain the row number 1,2 and 4.(should not contain row number 3)

When the user type 2, the result should contain the row number 2,3 and 4.

My current query statement is

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE 
string_id = "user_value" OR 
string_id LIKE "%-user_value" OR 
string_id LIKE "%/user_value" OR 
string_id LIKE "user_value-%" OR 
string_id LIKE "user_value/%" OR 
string_id LIKE "%-user_value-%" OR 
string_id LIKE "%/user_value/%" OR 
string_id LIKE "%-user_value/" OR 
string_id LIKE "%/user_value-"
```

Is there any other efficient and worth solution to replace this query?

Comment: You can use nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_id, '/', 1)` kind of functions and check if your value exists in the result. If you can create a SQL fiddle and provide some more examples then I can help with that. From your SQL, it feels that either your explanation is incomplete or your SQL is not correct. Consider example: `user_value = 1`, are `1-`, `2/1` or `/1` valid values for string_id?

Comment: yes. user_value = 1 will return 1-, 2/1 or /1. but the data in "string_id" not  contains this format.